# Лучший способ парсить поток XML?

Tags: xml, sax, java

День добрый!

Граждане, посоветуйте пожалуйста как быстрее всего запарсить большой XML, который приходит через `URLConnection`, то есть из веб, то есть идет из такого потока:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Я так понимаю, надо выбрать между `SaxParser` и обычной ручной обработкой каждой строки XML на предмет содержания ею тэга.

Что быстрее?
Потянет ли `SaxParser` поток, где будет пара сотен тысяч тэгов?
Каков предел такой системы загрузки XML по скорости и объему?

Comment: Канешно потянет.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы! Stax действительно неплох, простой и быстрый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> как быстрее всего запарсить большой
> XML

Если тут идёт о скорости работы конечного приложения, а не скорости программирования, то может у обычной ручной обработки будет какой-нибудь выигрыш в скорости работы (если узкое место - не чтение данных, а обработка). Но тут всё зависит от специфики задачи.

По поводу SAX - sax parser обрыботает любой объём данных.

Возможно, в некоторых случаях будет быстрее StAX (чем SAX). К примеру, нужно узнать, есть ли слово "ыыы" в документе? Оно нашлось в середине документа. Остальную часть документа можно и не читать даже. SAX, будет читать.

Answer (score 3):

SaxParser как раз и создан для того что бы читать из потока. Он не загружает весь хмл в память что бы прочитать определенный кусок xml ...